# Meaning of "to believe the impossible"

Tags: verbs, expressions

Does *to believe the impossible* mean

- to believe that everything is possible
- to believe that something seemingly impossible is actually possible
- something else?

Comment: It's a fairly vague (and IMHO vacuous) expression which can mean many things to many people. There's not even any consistency about whether *believing the impossible* is a good or a bad thing. It may mean you've got impressive powers of imagination and tenacity, or that you're ignorant and credulous, for example.

Comment: @Jasper: It would hardly even be a struggle to believe that your answer was "correct". Clearly you lack faith! :)

Comment: @Fumble: Jasper does not now not refrain from choosing not to disbelieve the not impossible: the seemingly possible is impossible.

Comment: @Jasper: What in the world? Your answer is fine!

Comment: Jesus wept! I'm an atheist, and even **I** have more faith than Jasper! :)

Comment: Atheists need faith just as much as anyone else; it's just what the faith is *in* that matters; evidently Jasper has lost faith in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"To believe the impossible"* to me sounds truncated. The phrase is familiar, true, but when thinking about it, I would rather see:

- *To believe **in** the impossible*, or
- *To believe the impossible **could be possible***
- *To believe **in that which is** impossible*

In its -- to me -- truncated form, it seems to imply that *"the impossible"* is an entity of its own, e.g. *to believe the rumours*.

Therefore I would interpret the sentence in question as:

*To believe that things which most people consider impossible, is actually possible*

Which is different from your options in that it uses a subjective viewpoint.  *To believe the impossible* to me feels more like the viewpoint of a free thinker, a radical, or whatever adjective you prefer for someone who is not satisfied with mainstream opinions (or generally accepted facts).

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the impression that it's used when you're asking someone to do a leap of faith and believe a story that person is unlikely to believe if it wasn't for you begging him to.

Answer (score 2):

As completely anecdotal evidence from my own experiences, believing the impossible refers to the action of **deciding** to believe in something which seems, at first blush, to be impossible.

Since our achievements can be limited by our aspirations, this phrase is usually said to inspire greater aspirations in the hearer.